# Android eclipse - Collect preferences failed

Tags: android, eclipse

I have updated the SDK to Android 4.4 and when i create a new project it showing error. please help me how to resolve this issue.

```
[2013-11-01 18:31:03 - Framework Resource Parser] Collect preferences failed, class junit/framework/TestCase not found in /home/android2/Desktop/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar
```

Comment: I'm still downloading.  But what specific project type are you creating.

Comment: Creating a test project with Target SDK version 4.4

Comment: what is the process u have followed to install the new SDK? i am having API level 18 and tried to update

Comment: SDK manager.  checked the new and updated clicked install then came to stack overflow to kill time.  Then went back and restarted eclipse.  Nothing unusual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was having the same issue and poked around a bit, and found a solution that worked well (apparently for others as well). This:

1. go Help | Install New Sofware...
2. select "Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/".
3. press "Select All"
4. press "Finish"

was posted [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788316/collect-preferences-failed-class-java-lang-autocloseable-not-found-in-c-progra)

It was also noted you may need to use https in the link above.