# Collect preferences failed, class java/lang/AutoCloseable not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator

I just update the android sdk API-19 and buildtool-19 from sdk manager. But in starting the eclipse it show the console error that are mention on the title.
And one more thing when i was created the avd for android 4.4 emulator that is not show in the list of running emulator. Please resolve this thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I already resolved it now.
Try the following steps

1. go **Help | Install New Sofware...**
2. *select* **Android Developer Tools Update Site** - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
3. press **Select All**
4. press **Finish**

Done

Comment: You may have an "No repository found error" error while installing the tools as I had. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10103295/1080954) is the solution for it.

Comment: Note that the url given might fail for you.  I needed to use the `https` path instead:  `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`.