# Installing Software has encountered a prob... - android

Tags: android, updates, android-framework

I get this problem in the console every time I launch the sdk,

`... Framework Resource Parser] Collect preferences failed, class java/lang/AutoCloseable not found in /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar`

In other to resolve this I found this solution: [Collect Preferences Failed by sunil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788316/collect-preferences-failed-class-java-lang-autocloseable-not-found-in-c-progra). However when I attempted the solution found here:

```
I had the same problem, but I already resolved it now. Try the following steps

1 go Help | Install New Sofware...
2 select "Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-  ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/".
3 press "Select All"
4 press "Finish"
Done
```

I get the following 'Problem Occurred':

[image]

I tried using https instead of http but I still get the problem. Can someone tell me whats wrong and how to resolve it please? It doesn't seem to cause any problems when running the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
Here is the link to adt plugin
Scroll down till you see a downloadable zip file of adt. 
Download it
Unpack it
And copy paste the files n folders of that zip file in to the eclipse folder 
If prompted for overwrite, select yes..
You will be good to go..

Comment: Thanks.This seems to work, i didnt follow your guidelines exactly but I did find the solution on that link. I just downloaded the zip and followed the original solution but chose the archive instead of the link.

Comment: Well the archive installation didn't worked for me soo i assumed it wudnt work for you either.. But anyways kudos to solved problem

Comment: Do you think its a bug in the latest update? I didnt have this problem until I updated to android api 19 the other day

Comment: Well it's like they support the latest version of eclipse distro. For now its kepler. So if you download eclipse of kepler package you will find no probs installing ADT but if you use indigo or helios or juno package then you might get troubles.. Its just my guess as i was using helios and i had to manually unpack the zip until recently i downloaded the kepler package and downloaded via https

Answer (score 14):

While updating, deselect "contact all update sites". worked for me.

```
1 go Help | Install New Sofware...
2 select "Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/".
3 press "Select All"
4 UNCHECK "contact all update sites"
5 press "Finish"
```

Cheers.

Comment: Three time i download that bundle but issue is same.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse Help->install new software->put below URL inside work with
URL ::https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

deselecting "contact all update sites" also worked for me.