# Android Eclipse creating update issue?

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi all am try to update  my eclipse but it is creating some issue, here am attach screen short.

[image]

why this happen any one have idea of this problem.

[image]

```
 An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
 session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile,    phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature,23.0.3.1327240
 No repository found containing:
```

Comment: Can you copy & paste the error message here? Too small, can't read.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630446/installing-software-has-encountered-a-prob-android

Comment: @Raptor check error log

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499563/no-repository-found-error-in-installing-adt-in-eclipse-indigo

Comment: @Raptor trying but not working

Comment: If u have upgraded to  23 then ur adt plugin won't support right now with direct upgrade. Try downloading normal eclipse and download the adt plugin and go ahead

Answer (score 3):

Simply unchecking “Contact all update sites during install to find required software” solved this problem for me.